# What is the difference between "tuyo" and "suyo"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, gramática

I see them both being used to represent possession. For example:

> El gato es suyo

and

> El gato es tuyo.

Are these sentences the same? What is the difference between these words?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use "tuyo" when we refer to the person as "tú".
We use "suyo" when we refer to the person as "usted".
We also use "suyo" when we refer to someone else's possessions.

Comment: So they both mean the same only one is formal and the other is informal?

Comment: Yes, but also "suyo" can be uses for someone else's possessions. When we say "El gato es suyo" we can be talking about "usted" or about "él/ella", the second one as "El gato es de él/ella"

Comment: So `tuyo` means "yours" and `suyo` means "his, hers, etc."

Comment: "tuyo" = yours   ||    "suyo" = yours or her-his

Answer (score 13):

> El gato es suyo.

Can have four meanings depending upon who you're talking to or the context:

- The cat is yours (formal speaking, if you're using 'Usted' as the person)
- The cat is his
- The cat is hers
- The cat is theirs

> El gato es tuyo.

Can only mean:

- The cat is yours

Comment: A little side question - "Sus gafas.": Is the "Sus" masculine or feminine in this sentence?

Comment: `Sus` has no gender, it's used either for masculine and feminine stuff. Note that it's different from `Suyos/Suyas` where the gender is specified: `Estas gafas son suyas`.

Answer (score 2):

Both `tuyo` and `suyo` are possessive adjectives.
Translating respectively, to `yours` and `yours`,`his`,`hers`,`theirs`

And since they are adjectives they follow the same gender rules.

They can also be used as nouns but only if the possessed object is already mentioned prior in context.

Example.. in english.

- My vehicle is better than yours.
- Your cat is fatter than his.
- Your photograph is uglier than his.

Translated respectively.

- Mi vehículo es mejor que lo suyo.
- Tu gato es mas gordo que lo suyo.
- Tu foto es mas fea que la suya.

I believe you can substitute the `lo`s for `el`s

Comment: The correct translations would be:
- Mi vehículo es mejor que el tuyo/suyo. (non-formal/formal)
- Tu gato es más gordo que el suyo.
- Tu foto es más fea que la suya.

Answer (score 1):

"tuyo" and "suyo" are both possesive adjectives.
You use "tuyo" when you are speaking in 2nd person or directly to a person in front of you.

For insance :

Este coche es tuyo -------->  This car is yours

You use "suyo" when you are speaking in third person or referring to a third person.

For insance :

Este coche es suyo -------->  This is her car / The car is hers

Comment: vea la respuesta de alonso.torres para más información

Comment: voy a confirmar que es mas completa.gracias