# How to say “Yours,” or “yours only" to close a letter to a loved one?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, correspondencia

Does one use “suyo” In closing a letter to a loved one, such as a spouse?

For example, I wish to write “only yours,” or “yours.”   I have searched my grammar textbook and Spanish dictionaries.  Perhaps it is an idiomatic expression.  I welcome feedback.

Comment: **Tuyo** is the word you are looking for.

Comment: Give me the phrase in english

Answer (score 1):

The closest translation is **Siempre tuyo**

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to take in account when closing a letter to a loved one. So, let's get started on what you would need in order to get the closing statement closest to what you desire to express.

First, the use of "**tuyo**" versus "**suyo**" which has previously been discussed in this [question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/4940/13575). In short, the difference in this case would be of familiarity: **Suyo** is more respectful and formal, while **tuyo** is more familiar.

Usually, when you address a loved one you do it in an informal manner, which would tip the scales in favor of using "**tuyo**"; however, there are cases where you still address a loved one (such as a parent or a grandparent) with respect, in which case it would be "**suyo**".

Keep in mind that some spouses refer to their partners respectfully, specially in cultures where arranged marriages are a norm. So, as a rule of thumb, if you would refer to your loved one as "*sir*" or "*madam*" use "**suyo**", if you wouldn't, use "**tuyo**".

This takes us to the second aspect to address: After deciding to use either "**suyo**" or "**tuyo**", you might need to modify it to match your gender. If you are a male, you don't need to make any modifications, if you are a female, you would use "**suy*a***" or "**tuy*a***".

The final part would be what you intend to convey with your closing statement. "*Yours*" would be simple, where you either use "**suy*o/a***" or "**tuy*o/a***", while "*Only yours*" might imply "*Exclusively yours*".

If your intention is to express "*Only yours*", the easiest way to translate it would be: "**Sólo suy*o/a***" or "**Sólo tuy*o/a***". This phrase would give you the most literal translation possible.

However, if you want to imply "*Exclusively yours*" or you want to be a little more creative, here are a few choices:

- Solamente (**s**/**t**)uy(**o**/**a**) (*Only yours*)
- Exclusivamente (**s**/**t**)uy(**o**/**a**) (*Exclusively yours*)
- Únicamente (**s**/**t**)uy(**o**/**a**) (*Uniquely yours*)
- Enteramente (**s**/**t**)uy(**o**/**a**) (*Entirely yours*)
- Completamente (**s**/**t**)uy(**o**/**a**) (*Completely yours*)
- Absolutamente (**s**/**t**)uy(**o**/**a**) (*Absolutely yours*)
- Indudablemente (**s**/**t**)uy(**o**/**a**) (*Undoubtedly yours*)
- Apasionadamente (**s**/**t**)uy(**o**/**a**) (*Passionately yours*)
- Eternamente (**s**/**t**)uy(**o**/**a**) (*Eternally yours*)
- Sincereamente (**s**/**t**)uy(**o**/**a**) (*Sincerely yours*)

For example, if you were a female and informal, you would use "*Solamente **t**uy**a***" but if you were a male and formal you would use "*Solamente **s**uy**o***".

Answer (score 0):

You can use **siempre** (**tuyo**/**suyo**) but **suyo** is more formal than **tuyo**.